# Interrupt a code after time Python Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, time, python-requests

I have a code that collects data from a url using:

```
queryParam = {"tags": [], "startTime": startTime , "endTime": endTime, "filter": filter }
x = requests.post(url, json=queryParam)
values = ast.literal_eval(x.text)['values']
```

I'm collecting data over a ear so it takes a long time and I want it to pass if it takes too long. This needs to work on windows, so I cannot use anything including SIGALRM such as interruptingcow.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use [Event.wait()](https://www.includehelp.com/python/event-wait-method-with-example.aspx)? Seems to me like wait() stops execution of the program without blocking it from running, so I don't see why it wouldn't work to delay your program with a `wait(timeout=time-to-wait)` call.

Comment: How can I use this to move past this after the wait? I imagine it is with threading, but can I kill a thread after a certain period of time and can I extract variables from said thread?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Event.wait() is unrelated to threading. My research found some additional options if you want to use threads in your package. Event.wait() will simply prevent the next instruction from executing until a set time has passed, or an event is triggered.